# Facing classnotfound exception while reading a snowflake table using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am trying to read a snowflake table from spark-shell. To do that, I did the following.

```
pyspark --jars spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.0-spark_2.4.jar,jackson-dataformat-xml-2.10.3.jar
Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Feb 20 2018 09:19:12)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
>>> spark = SQLContext(sc)
>>> spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('CHECK')
>>> sfOptions = {
... "sfURL" : "url",
... "sfAccount" : "acntname",
... "sfUser" : 'username',
... "sfPassword" : 'pwd',
... "sfRole" :    'role',
... "sfDatabase" : 'dbname',
... "sfSchema" :  'schema',
... "sfWarehouse" : 'warehousename'
... }
>>> SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE = 'net.snowflake.spark.snowflake'
>>> df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE).options(**sfOptions).option("query","select column from schema.table limit 1").load()
```

Once I run the load statement, I am facing the below classnotfound exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
```

In the above operation, there is nothing but reading a snowflake table and as per the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#label-spark-options), I passed the required jar file I started spark-shell.

The spark version that loads when I start pyspark is `version 2.3.2.3.1.5.37-1`
I tried with multiple versions of snowflake connector which are `2.3/2.4/2.8/3.0` and I also passed the jar file `jackson-dataformat-xml-2.10.3.jar` but I still see the same exception.

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: seems like you're missing `snowflake-jdbc` driver?

Comment: But why do I need a jdbc driver when I'm using connector jar? Where would I register it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run

```
pyspark --jars spark-snowflake_2.11-2.8.0-spark_2.4.jar,snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar
```

For the code related question :

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.config("spark.jars", "<pathto>/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar,<pathto>/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.7.1-spark_2.4.jar") \
.config("spark.repl.local.jars",
        "<pathto>/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar,<pathto>/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.7.1-spark_2.4.jar") \
.config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Oh, I am new to Python. How do I register the driver in code ?