# How to properly set variables for PySpark - Snowflake connection?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the doc and trying to run a simple script found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.
```

My code below. I also tried to set config option with the path to the jdbc and spark-snowflake jars located in `/Users/Hana/spark-sf/` directory but no luck.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config('spark.jars','/Users/Hana/spark-sf/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.9.jar,/Users/Hana/spark-sf/spark-snowflake_2.12-2.8.1-spark_3.0.jar') \
    .getOrCreate()

# Set options below
sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com",
  "sfUser" : "<user_name>",
  "sfPassword" : "<password>",
  "sfDatabase" : "<database>",
  "sfSchema" : "<schema>",
  "sfWarehouse" : "<warehouse>"
}

SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"


df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  "select * from table limit 200") \
  .load()

df.show()
```

How should I properly be setting variables? And which ones are needed to set? If someone can help to list out these steps I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try format as "snowflake" only

So your dataframe will have

```
df = spark.read.format("snowflake") \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  "select * from table limit 200") \
  .load()
```

or set `SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME` variable to

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "snowflake"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - I tried that and I'm now getting this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: snowflake.

Comment: Can you follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957222/facing-classnotfound-exception-while-reading-a-snowflake-table-using-spark/62959579#62959579

Answer (score 0):

I've been also struggling with the "Failed to find data source", while configured my local development environment.
After installing and setting my Environment Variables for:
`HADOOP_HOME`
`SCALA_HOME`
`SPARK_CLASSPATH`
`SPARK_HOME`
and updated the `Path` variable, I've installed the snowflake connector:

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/v2.7.2/tested_requirements/requirements_39.reqs
pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.7.2
pyspark --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.10,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.2-spark_3.1
```

I was trying to use snowflake datasource in my python code::

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MYAPP').setMaster("local[*]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark_sql = SQLContext(sc)

df = spark_sql.read.format("snowflake")\
  .options(**sfOptions)\
  .option("query", query)\
  .load()`enter code here`
```

But the pyspark still did not seem to know the required jars to support the extension of `snowflake` datasource.

In order to solve the issue, I've finally added the required packages to the `SparkConf`:

```
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName('MYAPP') \
    .setMaster("local[*]") \
    .set("spark.jars.packages", "net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.10,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.12:2.9.2-spark_3.1")
```

Note that I've used `spark.jars.packages` with the packages instead of `spark.jars`  with the full path to the jars